# disabled mat-stepper when the form not validate

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

i have this `mat-stper` . in this i have 3 component . every component have a special form .

i want all mat-steper is disabled until the form was validate .

for example in stpe one i have a register From , i want when the form was validate the use can be selected the step tow . and do this work for step three .

```
  <mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper="matHorizontalStepper" [linear]="true" *ngIf="!isMobileSize" class="mt-6">
    <mat-step>
      <ng-template matStepLabel> Register Email </ng-template>
      <register-email [myStepper]="stepper"></register-email>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
      <ng-template matStepLabel> Confirm Email </ng-template>
      <confirm-email [myStepper]="stepper"></confirm-email>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Register Information</ng-template>
      <register-information [myStepper]="stepper"></register-information>
    </mat-step>
  </mat-horizontal-stepper>
  
  <mat-vertical-stepper *ngIf="isMobileSize" [linear]="true" #stepper>
    <ng-template matStepperIcon="edit">
      <mat-icon [icIcon]="icDoneAll"></mat-icon>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template matStepperIcon="done">
      <mat-icon [icIcon]="icDoneAll"></mat-icon>
    </ng-template>

    <mat-step>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>{{ "REGISTER.EMAIL" | translate }}</ng-template>
      <register-email [myStepper]="stepper"></register-email>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>{{
        "REGISTER.CONFIRM_EMAIL" | translate
      }}</ng-template>
      <confirm-email [myStepper]="stepper"></confirm-email>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>{{
        "REGISTER.INFORMATION" | translate
      }}</ng-template>
      <register-information [myStepper]="stepper"></register-information>
    </mat-step>
  </mat-vertical-stepper>
```

and this is my register-email component :

```
    @Input() myStepper: MatStepper;

    registerEmailFG: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.InitialForm();
  }

  /*********************************
     Form Life Cycle 
   ********************************/

  InitialForm(): void {
    this.registerEmailFG = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])]
    })
    this.transportData.value$.subscribe(data => {
      if (data) {
        if(data.email)
        {
          this.registerEmailFG.patchValue({ email: data.email })
        }else{
          this.registerEmailFG.patchValue({ email: data })
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

**now how can i solve this problem ????**

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use @Output in your inner components:

- register-email
- confirm-email
- register-information

Then make your parent component listen to the vents emitted by your inner components.
That way you can notify the stepper if the form is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

@kianoush dortaj

You missed `stepControl` in your `mat-step`.

```
  <mat-step [stepControl]="registerEmailFG"></mat-step>
```

It may resolve your issue.

Thanks

Comment: my formGroup in into to the component . for example in stepper i have a `register-email` and into the `register-email` component i have a `registerEmailFG`

Comment: is it possible to move all `form-group` into your parent component?